# COBYLA optimization algorithm python

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I want to maximize the distance between two objects using the algorithm COBYLA. I have a 2d array of both x and y values for each object.

The variables subject to change are a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3. I want COBYLA to calculate which values for these variables maximize the distance the between two objects.

There are two constraints:

```
a1,a2,a3 >= 1.5

b1,b2,b3 <= 3.0
```

I have most of the code written, but I do not understand how to call this function. I would like my code to do 2000 iterations to ensure the best values for the variables. Here's what I have so far:

```
import sys

import numpy as np 

from scipy import optimize

from scipy.optimize import _cobyla

obj1_data = np.loadtxt('obj1_data.txt')

obj2_data = np.loadtxt('obj2_data.txt')

x_obj1 = obj1_data[:,0] #array of x-values for obj1

y_obj1 = obj1_data[:,1] #array of y-values for obj1

y_obj2 = obj2_data[:,0] #array of x-values for obj2

x_obj2 = obj2_data[:,1] #array of y-values for obj2
```

## cobya minimization

```
def cobyla(a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3):

    #~~~ OBJECT 1 ~~~#

    #OBJECT 1 RANGE (a1 to b1)

    #np.where returns elements, either x or y, depending on condition
    #find index of elements where (from a to b)
    xindex1 = np.where(np.logical_and(x_obj1 >= a1, x_obj1 <= b1))

    #make an x array that corresponds to x index
    obj1_xarray1 = x_obj1[xindex1]

    #find y values corresponding to x range
    obj1_yarray1 = y_obj1[xindex1]

    #integrate values in yarray to give summed value of x-values in array
    obj1_int1 = np.trapz(obj1_yarray1,x=obj1_xarray1)



    #OBJECT 1 RANGE (a2 to b2)
    xindex2 = np.where(np.logical_and(x_obj1 >= a2, x_obj1 <= b2))

    obj1_xarray2 = x_obj1[xindex2]

    obj1_yarray2 = y_obj1[xindex2]

    obj1_int2 = np.trapz(obj1_yarray2,x=obj1_xarray2)



    #OBJECT 1 RANGE (a3 to b3)
    xindex3 = np.where(np.logical_and(x_obj1 >= a2, x_obj1 <= b2))

    obj1_xarray3 = x_obj1[xindex3]

    obj1_yarray3 = y_obj1[xindex3]

    obj1_int3 = np.trapz(obj1_yarray3,x=obj1_xarray3)


    #~~~ OBJECT 2 ~~~#


    #OBJECT 1 RANGE (a1 to b1)
    #np.where returns elements, either x or y, depending on condition
    #find index of elements where (from a to b)
    xindex4 = np.where(np.logical_and(x_obj2 >= a1, x_obj2 <= b1))

    #make an earth x array that corresponds to x index
    obj2_xarray1 = x_obj2[xindex4]

    #find y values corresponding to x range
    obj2_yarray1 = y_obj2[xindex4]

    #integrate values in yarray to give summed value of x-values in array
    obj2_int1 = np.trapz(obj2_yarray1,x=obj2_xarray1)


    ##OBJECT 1 RANGE (a2 to b2)
    xindex5 = np.where(np.logical_and(x_obj2 >= a2, x_obj2 <= b2))

    obj2_xarray2 = x_obj2[xindex5]

    obj2_yarray2 = y_obj2[xindex5]

    obj2_int2 = np.trapz(obj2_yarray2,x=obj2_xarray2)


    #OBJECT 1 RANGE (a3 to b3)
    xindex6 = np.where(np.logical_and(x_obj2 >= a2, x_obj2 <= b2))

    obj2_xarray3 = x_obj2[xindex6]

    obj2_yarray3 = y_obj2[xindex6]

    obj2_int3 = np.trapz(obj2_yarray3,x=obj2_xarray3)



    #~~~~EQUATION THAT SHOULD BE OPTMIZED~~~#
    max = (((obj1_int1/obj1_int2) - (obj2_int1/obj2_int2))**2 +
           ((obj1_int3/obj1_int2) - (obj2_int3/obj2_int2))**2)**0.5
    return max
```

## Constraints

```
def constr1(a1,a2,a3):

    a1,a2,a3 >= 1.5

    return a1, a2, a3

def constr2(b1,b2,b3):

    b1,b2,b3 <= 3.0

    return b1,b2,b3



p = optimize.fmin_cobyla(cobyla, cons=[constr1,constr2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this method for creating a strategy for SGD Basket Trading.
Although I'm no expert on the topic, I have a fair idea. 
Try converting your objective and constraints into functions.
Call these functions then in your

```
x = fmin_cobyla(objtv_func,x0,constr_funcs,rhoend = 1e-7)
```

This should solve your problem of calling the cobyla optimizer.
If you encounter an error, you would also be able to see your exact point of error.

Hope this works for you! Good luck!